# MCSession ofen can't reconnect when app return to foreground from background

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I'm using Mutipeer Connectivity to make a chat app. At first, everything worked well and MCSession can connect with each other. But when user tap home button and then tap app icon, the apps disconnect with each other and often can't reconnect. But sometimes it can reconnect. The success is random.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(DidBecomeActive:)
                                                 name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didEnterBackground:)
                                                 name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

    NSString *displayname=[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    _MyPeerID=[[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:displayname];

}

- (void)DidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    if (notFirstLaunch==YES) {
        NSLog(@"DidBecomeActive");
        NSString *displayname=[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
        _MyPeerID=[[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:displayname];
        [self createSession];
        [self createAdvertiser];
        [self beginBrowsing];


    }
    notFirstLaunch=YES;

}

- (void)didEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"didEnterBackground");
    [_MySession disconnect];
    _MySession=nil;
    _MyBrowser=nil;
    _MyAdver=nil;


}



- (void)createSession
{
    _MySession=[[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:_MyPeerID];
    _MySession.delegate=self;
}


- (void)createAdvertiser
{
    _MyAdver=[[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:_MyPeerID discoveryInfo:nil serviceType:MyServiceType];
    _MyAdver.delegate=self;
    [_MyAdver startAdvertisingPeer];
}

- (void)beginBrowsing {
    _MyBrowser=[[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:_MyPeerID serviceType:MyServiceType];
    _MyBrowser.delegate=self;
    [_MyBrowser startBrowsingForPeers];
}
```

Comment: did u find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the code you've posted, nothing reconnects because in didEnterBackground you disconnect from the session and destroy the session, browser and advertiser. In DidBecomeActive you have a guard (notFirstLaunch) that means that the session and advertiser are only created the first time you become active, and NOT after you become active when you come back from being in the background.